# What method is best for having functions which instantiate other functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using this approach:

```
var __foo = new function(){
 var _id = null;
 function GetId(){
  return _id;
 }
 function SetId(id){
  _id = id;
 }
 return{
  GetId : GetId,
  SetId : SetId,
 };
}

var __fooFactory = function(){
 var _foos = [];
 var _autoIncFooId = 0;

 function CreateFoo(){
  var newFoo = new __foo();
  newFoo.SetId(_autoIncFooId++);
  _foos.push(newFoo);
 }

 return{
  CreateFoo : CreateFoo
 };
}
```

Should I be using prototypes more instead of this implementation? Is there an alternative to this approach? (I am open to jQuery ideas, but if so please keep them to 1.4.4 or note version compliance)

Comment: You definitely shoudn't use this method since there's a TypeError. Did you try running this? Are you sure you're comfortable enough with Javascript to be using inline `new`s?

Comment: @Triptych - I have used this already, works just fine. The new keyword allows the creation of unique objects.

Comment: @Triptych - Where do you think the TypeError is?

Comment: calling `__fooFactory.CreateFoo()` will raise a TypeError, because you're calling `new __foo()`, but the `new` statement on line 1 sets __foo to the return value of the inline function (a plain object) rather than the function itself, which is what I think you mean to do.

Comment: @Triptych - Doesn't throw an error for me, can you show the message you are getting? I am trying to create unique objects here. Mostly because I want to append them to the DOM when I am doing this. And if they are not unique a change in one place could result in the wrong element changing on the page.

Comment: I would review this as a potential source of ideas here: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/

Comment: TypeError: object is not a function
Line: var newFoo = new __foo();

Answer (score 2):

Foo constructor:

```
function Foo(i) {
    var id = i; // private

    this.getId = function () {
        return id;
    };

    this.setId = function (i) {
        id = i;
    };
}
```

Factory constructor:

```
function FooFactory() {
    var i = 0,
        foos = [];

    this.createFoo = function () {
        var foo = new Foo(i++);
        foos.push(foo);
        return foo;
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
var fooFactory0 = new FooFactory(),
    foo00 = fooFactory0.createFoo(), // getId() -> 0
    foo01 = fooFactory0.createFoo(); // getId() -> 1

var fooFactory1 = new FooFactory(),
    foo10 = fooFactory1.createFoo(), // getId() -> 0
    foo11 = fooFactory1.createFoo(); // getId() -> 1
```

If you want public `id`, you can use prototype:

```
function Foo(i) {
    this.id = i; // public
}

Foo.prototype.getId = function () {
    return this.id;
};

Foo.prototype.setId = function (i) {
    this.id = i;
};
```

What Crockford says about [*var Foo = new function () { .. }*](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/).

> It is never a good idea to put `new` directly in front of `function`. For example, `new function` provides no advantage in constructing new objects. By using `new` to invoke the function, the object holds onto a worthless prototype object. That wastes memory with no offsetting advantage.